# Add javascript in php mysql query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I know this sound weird but I need to be able to use a variable in javascript and use it inside a php mysqli query

I use the jQuery File Upload from blueImp. It's variable are store like this

```
{%=file.name%}
```

and I need to do something like this

```
$iq = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE mId='".$_GET['mId']."' AND file_name = '".{%=file.name%}."'");
```

of course this is not working because of the {}.

Anyone have a clue how to work with those kind of programming ?

Comment: Look into Ajax.  http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        //POST request sent
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("POST", "url_to_phpfile.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("yourvariable="+yourvariable);
```

Then you can use that variable in your php file like so:

```
$iq = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE mId='".$_GET['mId']."' AND file_name = '".$_POST["yourvariable"]."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot **directly** do this**.

- Javascript is something that will execute at client side(browser).
- PHP is a server side scripting language.

If you want to pass a Javascript variable in `PHP` , then you can do so through `AJAX`